# showing the completed drama "php","mysql"

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I'm still a beginner in web development. I created an online streaming website and I'm facing a problem with viewing the completed drama. 
I wanted the website to view all the drama that has been fully uploaded by the admin to the user on one page ..
this is my code :

```
<?php
  $check = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT title_s FROM drama");
  $sar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
$title_ss = $sar['title_s'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `drama` d INNER JOIN `episoded` e ON d.title_s= e.title_s WHERE d.title_s = '$title_ss'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM drama WHERE epnumber  = '$result'");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

     $title = $row['title_s'];
     $entitle = $row['entitle_s'];
            $imagelink = $row['imagelink'];

            echo'
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item lol">
          <div class="card h-10">
            <a href="http://localhost/project/main/series.php?title='.$title.'"><img class="card-img-top image"  src="'.$imagelink.'" alt=""></a>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">
                <a href="http://localhost/project/main/series.php?title='.$title.'">'.$entitle.'/'.$title.'</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 ';
 }
?>
```

it shows my only one result 
ps: I have two table one for the drama type the other one for the episode info..

Answer (score 0):

You are executing this code:

```
$result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM drama WHERE epnumber  = '$result'");
```

In the first line, y*ou get a number of rows* from the prior query.  I don't know how many rows you would expect, but regardless, mysqli_num_rows is going to return you an integer.

Then you query and use this number to search for one episode, which you display in your output block.

There is no mystery to what is happening:  you are not using mysqli_num_rows correctly, but even if you were, your second query is still going to only return one row, unless there are multiple rows in the drama table with the same epnumber.

Either way, ***the number of rows in the prior query has nothing to do with the epnumber***.

I would need to understand your schema better to determine the proper queries, but what you have clearly are incorrect.  You have multiple queries, so it's not clear what you are trying to do, but I have to wonder why you have a 'drama' table.  Do you also have a 'comedy' table?

You should not have separate tables for every genre of program.  You should have a few tables for all programs (for example, series & episode), and each program should be related to one or more genres (depending on your preference).